# Overloading Extraction and Insertion Operators pt2 C++

Tags: c++

This is my pt2 of my previously posted question which idk 
if its gonna be answered or not after I edited since it was
already considered 'answered' i think.

Ok so I'm now trying for output a + bi :

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, complex const& c) {
    return out << c.getReal() << "+" << c.getImag() << "i";
}
```

and for input:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, complex& c) {
    double h, j;
    if (in >> h >> "+" >> j >> "i") {
        c.set(h, j);
    }
    return in;
}
```

However I get the following error when I compile:

This is for line 181 of my complex.cpp file(class complex implementation file) where `if (in >> h >> "+" >> j >> "i") {`is located of the above function definition is located:

```
binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

the following are all for line 45(Note each error is separate,total of 7 for this line) of my complex.h file where `friend std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, complex& c);` protoype is located.

```
'istream':is not a member of 'std'

syntax error missing ';' before '&'

'istream':'friend' not permitted on data declarations

missing type specifier-int assumed. Note:C++ does not support default-int

unexpected token(s) preceding';'


namespace "std" has no member "istream"

namespace "std" has no member "istream"
```

the following are for line 46 of my complex.h file where

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, complex c);
```

is located

```
'ostream': is not a member of 'std'

syntax error: missing ';' before '&'

'ostream':'friend' not permitted on data declarations

missing type specifier -int assumed.Note: C++ does not support default-int

unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

namespace "std" has no member "ostream"

namespace "std" has no member "ostream"
```

I noticed both are the same type of errors. Note I have

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
```

both on the complex.cpp file and the main.cpp file

Comment: Most of the compiler errors are because you have neglected to `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to input into read only string literals in

```
if (in >> h >> "+" >> j >> "i")
```

Which is not going to work.  What you need to do is create a variable to store the text content of the input.  Since the content is not needed we can just toss it out when done.  That will give you something along the lines of

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, complex& c) {
    double h, j;
    char eater;
    if (in >> h >> eater >> j >> eater) { // eater now consumes the + and i
        c.set(h, j);
    }
    return in;
}
```

As for the errors in you header files you need to have `#include <iostream>` in your header file so the compiler knows what `istream` and `ostream` are.

Comment: Hmn that makes sense, But my ostream doesn't need fixes? I try to compiler it with the istream fix but still get 14 out of 15 of the same errors above ( just the binary '>>' error is gone now.)

Comment: @GustX DId you add `#include <iostream>` to the begining of complex.h?

Comment: Oh I wasn't sure which headers i'm supposed to add to where. Finally it compiles without errors, but now I'm trying to test my overloads using complex class objects I get 1 error called "unresolved externals", Should I edit this question or post a new one?(before I compiled without having written anything in the main.cpp file)

Comment: @GustX That should be a new question although you should see this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: damn, thats alot i will have to investigate later not much time left for this D: